# Cloud Functions - Unknown error while fetching the archive

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I've been unable to access the source code for any of my Cloud Functions across multiple Google Cloud Projects for well over a week. When clicking through to the Source tab of a function I see a greyed out area with the message "Unknown error while fetching the archive".

On clicking Edit I'm met with "We can't display source code of this function." The error persists even if I try to set up a new Cloud Function. Then I get an error with no accompanying message.

There doesn't seem to be any issue with billing, I've tried logging in as a different user and I'm unable to find any documentation online. Has anyone been able to resolve this successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most scenarios, this error arises due to billing issues related to the account. However, since you confirm your case is not so, I suggest you try logging in with an incognito window once.

If it doesn't help, make sure to try out the steps mentioned in [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/210063916).

Comment: I have posted an answer. Can you check if that helps?